# How can i fix the"preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug" terminated with exit code 1' issue?

Tags: python, json, docker, docker-compose

I am working with VScode on windows.When I try to debug `docker-build` command, it shows an `Error: The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1.` at `"preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug"` line in my **launch.json** file.

Here is `launch.json` file:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - General",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "general"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Here is `tasks.json` file:

```
version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "stocksight01b12:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "file": "sentiment.py"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```